# Getting Visual Studio to deploy a UDF to Return NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: varchar, sql-clr, functions, visual-studio-2013

I have a SQLCLR stored procedure with the following signature in Visual Studio 2013:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString ExecSql2Json(SqlString sql)
```

Or alternatively I've tried:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlChar ExecSql2Json(SqlChar sql)
```

Either way the parameter and return type gets defined as `NVARCHAR(4000)`. I'd like them to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

I know I can manually write my own `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement to have fine grain control. Is there any option anywhere to change the deploy DDL generated by SQL Server or do I just have to manually add a script to drop and read the UDF with the proper signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a `SqlFacet` for the return value. This is the same as specifying a `SqlFacet` for an input parameter, except you prefix it with `return:`

For `(max)` length, use `MaxSize=-1` in the `SqlFacet` attribute, example follows:

```cs
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction
        (
        DataAccess=DataAccessKind.None,
        SystemDataAccess=SystemDataAccessKind.None,
        IsDeterministic=true,
        IsPrecise=true
        )
    ]
    [return: SqlFacet(IsFixedLength=false, IsNullable=true, MaxSize=-1)] 
    public static SqlString ScalarFunction1
        (
            [SqlFacet(IsFixedLength=false, IsNullable=true, MaxSize=-1)] 
            SqlString input
        )
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

The T-SQL script generated for this SQLCLR function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ScalarFunction1]
(@input NVARCHAR (MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR (MAX)
AS
 EXTERNAL NAME [Library].[UserDefinedFunctions].[ScalarFunction1]
```